# Tailwind CSS served with MIME type text/html

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, tailwind-css

I'm having an error on my project where I get this message:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/src/output.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I'm using React 18.2.0 and Tailwindcss 3.3.2.
My tailwind.config.js is:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        poppins: ['Poppins', 'sans-serif'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

and i'm serving static files to the client using[code below] on the server side:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The problem happening on each of the pages of my project.
the reason I think, is because I'm using a proxy settings on my client side:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8800/api",
```

I'm using this proxy on all of my routes (post, get, put..) and I can't remove it.

I would greatly appreciate your help!

I tried changing the Static paths - with no success.
I tried to remove the proxy from package.json on the client side - solved the problem but created greater problems.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Express's documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) (emphasis mine):

> For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named `public`:
>
> ```js
> app.use(express.static('public'))
> ```
>
> Now, you can load the files that are in the `public` directory:
>
> ```
> http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
> http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
> http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
> http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
> http://localhost:3000/hello.html
> ```
>
> Express looks up the files **relative to the static directory**, so **the name of the static directory is not part of the URL**.

Hence, it seems like your `output.css` file is located at `<project-root>/src/output.css` and so you would request it via the URL `http://localhost:3000/output.css`.